# Sort array of structs

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, sorting, struct

Sorting array of structs on the first struct field is straightforward.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([("e", 2, 20), ("f", 2, 10), ("d", 2, 30), ("b", 1, 20), ("c", 1, 10), ("a", 1, 30)],)],
    'col1 array<struct<f1:string,f2:int,f3:int>>')

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- col1: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- f1: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- f2: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- f3: integer (nullable = true)

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                    |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{e, 2, 20}, {f, 2, 10}, {d, 2, 30}, {b, 1, 20}, {c, 1, 10}, {a, 1, 30}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The above data can be sorted like this:

```py
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.sort_array("col1"))
df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                    |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{a, 1, 30}, {b, 1, 20}, {c, 1, 10}, {d, 2, 30}, {e, 2, 20}, {f, 2, 10}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**But how to sort based on several fields, with differing orders?**

E.g. how to sort by `f2 asc, f3 desc`?

(In this particular example, the result will be the same as above - `abcdef`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy way**

If you can achieve *BOTH* of these, you will have a simpler code:

- rearrange struct fields so that *fields for sorting would be placed at the beginning*
- modify the values in fields for sorting so that *the order would be the same for all the sort fields* (e.g. only ascending)

If you're lucky to have both conditions satisfied, just do `F.sort_array("col1"))`.

For the rest of us, let's continue.

Tip: when possible, we can create new struct fields at the beginning of struct just in order to use the simple sorting method (there's an example in a few sentences below).

Rearranging fields in structs of array can be done like this:

```py
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.expr("transform(col1, x -> struct(x.f2, x.f3, x.f1))"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                    |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{2, 20, e}, {2, 10, f}, {2, 30, d}, {1, 20, b}, {1, 10, c}, {1, 30, a}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Modifying values in order to equalize the order type can easily be done if you deal with integers. E.g. if we want the final sort to be `f2 asc, f3 desc`, we can add `-` sign before f3, so that we could use the same (e.g. ascending) order type for both fields.

```py
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.expr("transform(col1, x -> struct(x.f2, -x.f3, x.f1))"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                          |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{2, -20, e}, {2, -10, f}, {2, -30, d}, {1, -20, b}, {1, -10, c}, {1, -30, a}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sorting `f2 asc, f3 desc` (f3 was modified, so that asc would work for both fields). The goal was to get abcdef:

```py
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.sort_array("col1"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                          |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{1, -30, a}, {1, -20, b}, {1, -10, c}, {2, -30, d}, {2, -20, e}, {2, -10, f}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Another example if you care not to change the values and/or order inside the struct. `struct(x.f2, -x.f3) _sort` inner struct is created just for ordering at the beginning and immediately after the sort it's removed.

```py
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.expr("sort_array(transform(col1, x -> struct(struct(x.f2, -x.f3) _sort, x.f1, x.f2, x.f3)))"))
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.expr("transform(col1, x -> struct(x.f1, x.f2, x.f3))"))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                    |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{a, 1, 30}, {b, 1, 20}, {c, 1, 10}, {d, 2, 30}, {e, 2, 20}, {f, 2, 10}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**More elaborate way**

Comparator function may be needed in more demanding cases. It is passed as the second parameter in [`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_sort) function in SQL API. PySpark doesn't have the option for such parameter. In the function, `l` means left, `r` means right. It loops through elements in array and finds the position for them based on the specified `case` conditions.

To make the ordering `f2 asc, f3 desc`, we first describe conditions for f2, then for f3.

```py
df = df.withColumn("col1", F.expr("""
    array_sort(
        col1,
        (l, r) -> case when l.f2 < r.f2 then -1
                       when l.f2 > r.f2 then 1
                       when l.f3 > r.f3 then -1
                       when l.f3 < r.f3 then 1
                       else 0
                  end)
    """
))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |col1                                                                    |
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# |[{a, 1, 30}, {b, 1, 20}, {c, 1, 10}, {d, 2, 30}, {e, 2, 20}, {f, 2, 10}]|
# +------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```